# Shared file size limited to local drive size

Tags: network-share, disk-space-utilization, directory, alfresco

I wish to use alfresco as a shared file system using Windows (XP, 7 & 8) Explorer.
I can access the shared folder, and can modify files on it.
I can mount the alfresco filesystem, and it mounts automatically at each start.
I have admin access both on alfresco and the AD.

However, Windows Explorer tells me that the alfresco folder has 150 Gio space, which is my local drive size, not the size of the alfresco's server's drive.
Furthermore, when I add a file to the alfresco drive, I lose space both on the alfresco drive AND on my local drive. 
Finally, when I delete this file, I don't get the space back.

How should I do to have an Alfresco drive working in a classical way (using the server disk space and not the client's) ?

Version Alfresco : 4.2.c -
Version Community -
Linked to an Active Directory -
Windows Server 2012 -
Protocole used : Webdav

Comment: Doesn't webdav involve downloading to the local client? (I don't know, that's why I'm asking.) Also, by "Windows file manager", do you mean the Windows Explorer? [File Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Manager_%28Windows%29) was retired by Windows 95 and NT 4.0.

Comment: Yes, I do mean Windows Explorer.
I haven't been able to find if webdav involve downloading to the local client. Will look for this.

Comment: Where is Alfresco installed? On your machine, or elsewhere?

Comment: On a distant Windows Server 2012. The size displayed on the shared folder on my machine is the size of my local HDD, not the distant disk storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved my problem by switching to CIFS.
Alfresco's CIFS path can be found In the webclient go the company home->view details -> right click view on CIFS ->Copy shortcut ->take the url and manipulate the url bit..[ As you have to replace "/" with "\"]